# What kite-surfing equipment should I start with?

Tags: equipment, surfing

To start with, find below some of my characteristics/equipement:

- 15 years of age
- 1.92 m / 6.3 ft
- 65 kg / 150 pounds
- I'm in, what I consider to be, reasonable physical condition
- Pretty good with trainer kite (3 m / 9.8 ft without bar)

Does this suffice for a beginner? What kind of equipment should I start with?

Comment: FYI, meta discussion: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/474/are-questions-in-the-form-manner-how-can-i-get-started-in-sport-on-topic

Comment: have you already asked your kite instructor? Where will you kite the most? Ask there at a kite school or experienced kiters who know the spot very well.

Answer (score 5):

Starter equipment is very individual and depends on the locations and conditions you are going to be riding in. From your height, weight and age perspective there are no limitations that would be limiting the selection.

In general, it is a good practice to have lessons with certified (IKO as one of many possibilities or something else) school or instructor, who can also advise on the types of kites and boards that would be suitable for you in the beginning.

Also they will have the right equipment for carrying out the initial lessons and actually allows you to experience different gear and find the ones that are best for you. Considering that there is possibility for physical harm, I wouldn't recommend going out and experimenting with high power traction kites without decent supervision.